# Update values in spreadsheet using SQL

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to update values in a spreadsheet using a SQL query?
This script works for reading.
I need write value  using SQL.

Thanks!

```
function testReadSQL() {

 var queryString = 'SELECT A,B WHERE B > 1' 
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheetId}/gviz/tq?'+
            'range=A1:B' +
            '&tqx=out:csv' +
            '&sheet=Sheet1' +
            '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(queryString);
  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()   
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use PowePivot.
 You will have to do your own research, it is a big topic.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to Apps Script connecting to SQL database and its operations, [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) is what's available as of now.

> This service allows scripts to connect to JDBC-compliant databases,
>   including Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle.
>   See also the guide to JDBC.

Comment: The above code is loaded using SQL data from the Google spreadsheet, not the database.
But I would like to edit the table, not just to read it.

Comment: again, that's what apps scritps support as of now